# Recommended settings for .Aspnet.Cookies and __RequestVerificationToken

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I am trying to adhere to the recommended settings for cookies for my MVC web application. My intention is to set ***HttpOnly = true***, ***Secure = true*** and ***SameSite = Strict*** settings to cookies wherever appropriate.

I have two questions in this regard.

1. I am a bit confused on the settings for ***.AspNet.Cookies*** and ***__RequestVerificationToken*** cookies. Can someone please help me understand the purpose of these cookies. I roughly understand .AspNet.Cookies is Owin cookie and __RequestVerificationToken is used to prevent anti- forgery attack. But this is not enough make an informed decision on what is the recommended settings for these cookies. I believe setting HttpOnly and Secure attributes to these cookies would not hurt, but not sure on the SameSite setting, especially that I have got intentions to use a third party identity provider in near future.
2. As a trial attempt, I set the cookie settings to *Strict, HttpOnly* and *Secure* for "*__requestverificationtoken*" and *.aspnet.cookies* in *Application_PreSendRequestHeaders* in Global.asax.cs. This seems to have worked in setting these cookie attributes, but I am not sure whether this is the right way to do it. Is there a better way to setting the attributes for these cookies?

Comment: How did you configurate it in global.asax.cs?